# Flip card in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

Is there any way to fix transition of flip `<div>` with `rotateY(180deg)` in Internet Explorer? On hover, `<div>` disappear and then will appear after animation. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wyov8y50/5/) is fiddle.

```css
#card {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

#foreground, #background {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

#foreground {
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateZ(1px) rotateY(0deg);
}

#background {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card:hover #foreground {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card:hover #background {
  transform: translateZ(1px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
    <div id="foreground">
        Foreground
    </div>
    <div id="background">
        Background
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `translateZ`. The advantage of attempting to force GPU won't be noticeable for a simple `transform` such as this.